# I got error saying IndexError: list index out of range. how do I fix this?

Tags: python, list, index-error

```
   res = [3, 1, 1, 5, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 1, 5, 3]      

   while not i>(len(res)-1):
        if res[i]==res[i+1]:
            answer+=2
            i+=2
        else:
            i+=1
```

The variable "answer" is supposed to count duplicated numbers that are placed next to each other. For some reason, I get the error saying IndexError: list index out of range. How do I fix this?

Comment: What happens when `i == len(res) - 1`? The condition `not i > (len(res) - 1)` is satisfied, but then you execute `if res[i] == res[i+1]`. What is `i + 1`, then, and should `res` have an element at that index?

Comment: Try to reason it out: what is the largest value of `i` that satisfies the `while` loop condition? What happens if you try to use that value in the `if` condition - in particular, is `res[i+1]` valid?

Comment: Anyway, what should happen if the input data has 3 or more of the same value in a row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about giving it this approach?

```
res = [3, 1, 1, 5, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 1, 5, 3]
answer = 0
start = 0
while start < len(res):
    if start + 1 < len(res):
        if res[start] == res[start + 1]:
            answer += 1
            start += 2
        else:
            start += 1
    else:
        start += 1
print(answer)
```

Comment: This will only count duplicates, but if the input data has 3 or more of the same value in a row, a different approach will be used.

Answer (score 4):

Let's start off by simplifying the code a bit. The condition

```
not i > (len(res) - 1)
```

can be converted to

```
i <= (len(res) - 1)
```

which can be further converted to

```
i < len(res)
```

This means that `i` will always be less than the length of `res`, which makes it a valid index. However, within the body of the `while`, on this line:

```
if res[i]==res[i+1]:
    ...
```

we indexed `res` with `i + 1`, which for the last possible value of `i` will be an invalid index (`i + 1` will be equal to `len(res)`). We have to ensure that not only `i` is less than `len(res)`, but *also* that `i + 1` is less than `len(res)`, giving us this fixed version of the code:

```
while i + 1 < len(res):
    if res[i] == res[i + 1]:
        answer += 2
        i += 2
    else:
        i += 1
```

Running this code on your example `res` gives an `answer` of 4, which looks right.

Answer (score 1):

If you you want to count overlapping pairs also, you can use this approach:

```
res = [3, 1, 1, 5, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 1, 5, 3]
for i, j in zip(res, res[1:]):
    if i == j:
        amount += 2
```

Another approach could be:

```
for i, _ in enumerate(res):
    if i < len(res) - 1 and res[i] == res[i+1]:
        amount += 2
```